# Unable to start Fedora from USB

Tags: dual-boot, fedora

I already installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu and Fedora. I created Live USB with command:

```
sudo dd if=Fedora-Live-Desktop-x86_64-19-1.iso of=/dev/sdb1
```

But I am not able to boot from USB. My computer simply starts Ubuntu without any error message.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install to sdb, you installed to a partition sdb1.

If Fedora is a hybrid ISO then this should work.

```
sudo dd if=Fedora-Live-Desktop-x86_64-19-1.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Make absolutely sure that sdb is the correct drive. This will overwrite whatever sdb is and old data on that drive will not be recoverable.

Comment: I did not notice that krishna had written to a partition...

Comment: Thanks. This answer worked and I am able to Try Fedora from USB.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select to boot from it - press <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>↵</kbd>, or whatever it prompts you to press to enter the boot device selection screen. Then select USB HDD, with the name of the manufacturer of the memory stick next to it.

Comment: I did that. After selecting USB, it doesn't start Fedora from USB but starts Ubuntu in my computer.