# Problem burn blank dvd-RW "linux-windows"

Tags: boot, system-installation, dvd, disk-formatting

Neither windows nor any linux system burn blank dvd-rw or blank dvd-r. First time, first experience. And i need it urgently because I need install Fedora 10 for study purposes which isn't getting installed in any other manner . So, the only option is dvd. Although i have a fedora 10 original live cd as well as installer dvd but with errors. So, any one help please. I have only 2 days left.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Neither windows nor fedora are on-topic here*

Comment: Take note of the system you're install & the actual errors.  Ubuntu has *five* different installers available selected by the media you download/use to install; knowing which you're using helps interpret the actual error message & what must be done, but we can't read your screen & thus interpret your actual error messages anyway; so I suggest you read them.  Fedora 10 however is long out of date, so few may recall the older messages anyway (*even if you'd provided them*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to start Fedora from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382560/unable-to-start-fedora-from-usb)